# How to get erased type at compile time?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-3

In Scala 2, there is a function `TypeApi#erasure` described as follows

```
The erased type corresponding to this type after
all transformations from Scala to Java have been performed.
```

How to get erased `Type` for a given `TypeRepr` in Scala 3?

Comment: Can you share slightly more context on what you want to achieve? I guess this is part of a macro?

Comment: Note that you can get a "hint" on available methods of `TypeRepr` by looking at https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/master/library/src/scala/quoted/Quotes.scala#L2354 until everything is properly documented

Comment: Generally `ClassTag` and `TypeTag` should be sufficient for most of cases, but we definitely need more info to give a detailed solution

Answer (score 1):

I have also asked this question on dotty Gitter and it came out, that currently there is no available API for getting erased types.
Then I created a [dotty feature request](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-feature-requests/issues/209) in which you can find possible workarounds.